# javascript array of string to json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array:

```
data = [
    "Id = 2",
    "time = 10:59",
    "Topic = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "GUEST3",
    "Role = GS",
    "Infos = Connecticut",
    "GUEST4",
    "Role = HS",
    "Infos = Delaware",
    "GUEST5",
    "Role = CS",
    "Infos = Hawaii"
]
```

How can I make it a JSON object like this:

```
data = [   
 {    
    Id : 2,  
    time : 10:5',
    Topic : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,  
    GUEST3:
           {
             Role : GS,
             Infos : Connecticut,
           }
   GUEST4:
           {
            Role : HS,
            Infos : Delaware,  
   GUEST5:
           {
            Role : CS,
            Infos : Hawaii
           }
 }
```

Comment: That is not an array.That's not even valid javascript syntax.

Comment: I guess you forgot the quotes (?)

Comment: I removed them for clarity but will put it back.

Comment: Is something not working with `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: it does return same array

Comment: What have you tried? For the strings that contain a `=`, you can just use `.split(' = ')` to break them up into name-value pairs. You'll need to implement some logic to handle the child objects but it shouldn't be too difficult. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried JSON.stringify on W3schools,com but it did not work.

Comment: @mamesaye can you check below my answer.

Comment: Why do you have that array? This shouldn't be solved with JavaScript, IMO.

Comment: this is what I were given.

Comment: @mamesaye The question is quite different from when I made my initial comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code that will do it.

I've commented the code but the basic gist is it will look at each string in the array and then decide if it's a key and value or just another layer down into the object.

```js
const data = ["Id = 2", "time = 10:59", "Topic = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "GUEST3", "Role = GS", "Infos = Connecticut", "GUEST4", "Role = HS", "Infos = Delaware", "GUEST5", "Role = CS", "Infos = Hawaii"];

// Declaring new object
let obj = {};
// Place to remember current level of object
let level;

// For every bit of the array
for (let item of data) {
  // If it contains an equals
  if (item.includes('=')) {
    // Split it into two stings
    let split = item.split('=');
    let key = split[0].trim();
    let cont = split[1].trim();
    // If we're already on a lower level like GUEST3 put it in there
    if (level) {
      obj[level][key] = cont
    } else {
      // Or just place the new data at the top level
      obj[key] = cont
    }
  } else {
    // If there's no equals we want to go down a layer
    level = item;
    obj[item] = {};
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

I hope this is helpful if you struggle to understand what is going on feel free to leave a comment.

**EDIT:**

I've mixed together the three answers you got to make a bit of a better answer.

```js
const data = ["Id = 2", "time = 10:59", "Topic = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "GUEST3", "Role = GS", "Infos = Connecticut", "GUEST4", "Role = HS", "Infos = Delaware", "GUEST5", "Role = CS", "Infos = Hawaii"]

let aO = o = {};
data.map(a => a.split(' = ')).forEach(e => {e.length > 1 ? aO[e[0]] = e[1] : aO = o[e] = {}});
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: Your input array looks very unusual and non-standard. If this really is how you receive your data, then you can use the code below to process it. However, I would recommend that you doublecheck, and if at all possible, try to alter the backend (or wherever this data comes from) to provide a standard JSON string or JavaScript object.

```js
var data = [
  "Id = 2",
  "time = 10:59",
  "Topic = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "GUEST3",
  "Role = GS",
  "Infos = Connecticut",
  "GUEST4",
  "Role = HS",
  "Infos = Delaware",
  "GUEST5",
  "Role = CS",
  "Infos = Hawaii"
];

var result = {};
var putInto = result;
for (let token of data) {
  if (token.indexOf('=') != -1) {
    let nameValue = token.split('=');
    let name = nameValue[0].trim();
    let value = nameValue[1].trim();
    putInto[name] = value;
  } else {
    let child = {};
    result[token] = child;
    putInto = child;
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your way of going down a layer is much neater than mine 

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to format the data properly. One way is to make it and array of arrays.

```
const str =  ["Id = 2","time = 10:59","Topic = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","GUEST3","Role = GS" ,"Infos = Connecticut","GUEST4","Role = HS","Infos = Delaware","GUEST5","Role = CS","Infos = Hawaii"]

const formatted = str.map(e => e.split('='))
```

then you can use something like [_.fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#fromPairs) from lodash

```
const obj = _.fromPairs(formatted);
```

And you got a PLAIN json. It's not exactly what you need but you can start with.